# How do we select top 20% and bottom 80% records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the top 20% ordered results and also remaining (bottom 80%) in a table.

when I do

```
select top (20)percent from table 1
```

and later

```
select top (80)percent from table 1 order by desc
```

as two different queries, I get the result. But my problem here is, if the record has the same values for the ordered column, then I might pick the same record again, as the selection is not content.

Can you suggest with any good way so that I can select the top 20% distinctly and remaining 80% records in a table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get your top 20 percent is:

```
select top (20) percent from table1 order by <something>
```

If you want the remaining 80% it's everything that's not in the top 20%; so:

```
select * from table1
except
select top(20) percent from table1 order by <something>
```

Comment: Thank you @Martin; it should be unique after this so I guess it depends on the payload (i.e. whether the OP wants it to be unique on something other than the columns returned).

Comment: To make it deterministic they would need to add a tiebreaker that is unique.